# Should the "Website" structured data be used only on the homepage?

Tags: seo, html, structured-data, markup

I have combined the following json scripts into a single one as I found this should be the best practice:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitename

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox

So the script is ok and located only on my homepage.

On google documentation page about sitelinks-searchbox it specifies to only use it on the homepage. But on the part about the sitename it does not.

So I am thinking that maybe I did wrong and wrongfully combined the two scrips instead of using the sitename one on all my pages I only used it on the homepage.

Can anyone confirm this please?

Comment: Did you see [*Where should I put Site Name structured markup?*](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/98171/17633) and does [my answer there](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98179/17633) answer your question? (tl;dr: Google doesn’t document if they only look on the homepage for their Site Name feature)

Answer (score 1):

You can use structured data on all your website pages. I think that you will get proper guideline from these article.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/enhance-site

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data